# Do I need tickets for the Bellagio Conservatory and Botanical Garden in Las Vegas?

Tags: tickets, las-vegas

Do we need to buy tickets to visit this place? Can those who are not staying at Bellagio visit this place?

Comment: Did you try their websites?

Answer (score 3):

There are no restrictions posted on the [website](https://www.bellagio.com/en/entertainment/conservatory-botanical-garden.html), and the entry on the Las Vegas tourism site, Vegas.com, similarly notes [no restrictions](https://www.vegas.com/attractions/on-the-strip/bellagio-conservatory/) and that no reservations required.

The display is free, open 24-hours in-season, and accessible to whoever has access to the hotel lobby, i.e. the public.

Answer (score 1):

I've walked into it several times.  There's no form of admission control.  You do not have to be a guest there--we are locals, we have never stayed in the Bellagio.

(Just to keep this current:  Sep 2018, still no access control.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that everyone passing in Bellagio can visit the garden.  It will be the first example of a town requiring a stay in order to visit an attraction. You can book a room in another village, town or even country (Switzerland is not that far).

For tickets more info at https://g.co/kgs/xBXhQn

Edit: this is valid for the original question ~that did not mention Las Vegas~. I am aware is of little value now as for info about tickets, opening time and so on can be easily found in internet without asking SE travel. And this independent of being the Tour Eiffel the original or a copy.

Comment: Dear Downvoter: I think editing the original question would be more helpful than downvoting an answer that didn't see the tiny tag. (You do know the LV Bellagio is not the original, right?)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The question and both answers are getting downvoted, so someone out there is just being grinchy.

Comment: I can even delete my answer as for currently has not attinence at all. I have to look in the web version. In app it doesn't seem possible.